# Как реализовать сравнение / определении схожести изображения

Tags: c#, изображения, нейронные-сети, сравнение

Работаю на проектом, столкнулся с задачей где нужно определить является ли изображение 2 копией или фрагментом(искаженным) изображения 1(оригинал) при этом у них может быть не масштабное искажения разрешения или графические искажения водная марка, текст, зеркальность[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Возможно ли реализовать данную задачу на сверточной нейронной сети, или это не подходящая задача для неё и это решается сложным по пиксельным сравнением?

Буду рад получить пример или логику решения

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Лучше копать в сторону SIFT/SURF и их аналогов. Библиотека OpenCV.

https://docs.opencv.org/3.3.0/da/df5/tutorial_py_sift_intro.html

Пример ссылки с реалицией на python, но переписать на C# проблемы быть не должно.
https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_feature2d/py_matcher/py_matcher.html